# Directly open page in text editor

Tags: editor

In wordpress, 
currently I am facing one problem that, when I'm clicking on page edit the editor directly opens in visual tab so, How to directly open page editor in text tab??? Does anyone have a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your themes functions.php file and it will default to the editors text view...

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "html";') );
```

Comment: Thank you but I have added this code into function.php but it is not working.